# contacts are not showing when I don't add a phone number

Tags: contacts

Contacts aren't showing when I don't add a phone number.

I add tap the phone icon, I tap the person icon with the plus, I enter a name and email address.  I tap "done". It says "contact saved".   Then I hit back and look at the list and it's not there when it should be. I restart the phone and it's still not there.

Comment: Does it show in the People or Contacts app? Because the phone app contact list usually only shows contacts with phone numbers, but the People/Contacts app should show all contact, similarly the Email app usually does not show contacts without email addresses.

Comment: @acejavelin yes I know, see my answer. I answered my own question.

Comment: I have to wonder why you want contacts with no phone number to show up in your dialer application, of what use is that?

Comment: I didn't say I did want them to show in the dialer application I just said I want to see them i.e. see them somewhere.  I wasn't aware of "contacts" or "people".  (or was aware of "contacts", though couldn't see it, and it turned out it was called "people").

Answer (score 0):

One semi-workaround is to add 0 for phone number, though that won't deal with contacts not showing prior to that i.e. when no number was entered at all.

What will work though is look for an app called "contacts" or "people". That app will list all contacts including ones where no phone number was entered.  That's  the solution. So those contacts aren't lost.

If you don't see the "contacts" or "people" app, then you could check if it's installed under settings..apps..all.  And you could try putting it in safe mode by holding the power button until it says "power off", and then when it says "power off", hold power off.  Then it asks to go into safe mode, then say ok, and let it restart into safe mode. Then see if you see the app, to make sure a third party app wasn't blocking it.. hopefully you will see it.  I saw it I think even in normal mode, it was just called "people" rather than "contacts. Whether it's "people" or "contacts" might depend on OS version.